# Mock two ObjectRepositories in Syfmony PHPUnit Tests

Tags: symfony, mocking, phpunit

A method from my `MyClass` class I'd like to test looks like this:

```
public function needs()
{
    $domains = $this->em->getRepository(WebDomain::class)->findBy(array(
        'client' => $this->client
    ));

    $hosting = $this->em->getRepository(WebHosting::class)->findBy(array(
        'client' => $this->client
    ));

    if($domains !== null && $hosting !== null){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Looking at the [documentation of Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html#mocking-the-repository-in-a-unit-test) I create a test like this:

```
public function testNeeds()
{
    $em = $this->createMock(ObjectManager::class);
    $client = new Client();

    /**
     * Add WebHosting to Client
     */
    $webHosting = new WebHosting();
    $webHosting->setClient($client);

    /**
     * Create a new WebDomain for Client/WebHosting
     */
    $webDomain = new WebDomain();
    $webDomain->setClient($client);
    $webDomain->setWebHosting($webHosting);
```

I know how to create a mocked repository (the needed `$domains` for example):

```
$domains = $this->createMock(ObjectRepository::class);
$domains->expects($this->any())
    ->method('findBy')
    ->willReturn($client->getWebDomain());

$em->expects($this->any())
    ->method('getRepository')
    ->willReturn($domains);

$myClass = new MyClass($client, $em);
```

So from my understanding, this creates a mock that whenever the method `findBy` is called, return the `$domains`, but what do I have to add in order to return the needed `$hosting`?

I suspect it has something to do with the `$this->any()`, I assume I have to narrow it down to `expects(WebDomain::class)` (which does not work ofc).

Since I am fairly new to UnitTests in Symfony (and in general) pointing me to the right manual might help as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you case you should return different `Repository` based on argument passed to `getRepository` method. Something like:

```
$emMock
    ->method('getRepository')
    ->will($this->returnValueMap([
       [WebDomain::class, $webDomainRepositoryMock),
       [WebHosting::class, $webHostingRepositoryMock)
    ]));
```

Note: remember to configure `findBy` for both repositories.